# Have Windows add the current date to a filename during the save process

Tags: windows, shell, scripting

Is it possible to pass a variable in along with a Windows input box for filename?  I'd like the variable to be the current date.  The best way I can describe this is..think of the window that comes up whenever you choose "SAVE AS" in Windows. In addition to typing out the name of the file that I want, I also want the current date with the filename; I don't neeed it formatted in any an exact way.  I just need the current date as part of the filename.

Comment: If you are writing the file then before opening the file for writing add the date

Answer (score 1):

You may not need to do anything. After the file-save-as dialog box returns, it returns the file name selected by the user. You can do whatever you want with that file name before actually saving it to disk.

But if you need to do a customization in place while the dialog is visible, I think you want a [Windows common dialog box extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  This is a code hook that allows you to customize the standard Windows file open (or file save) dialog within your own code.

The most obvious example of a file open dialog extension is the one written for Notepad. From the File menu in Windows Notepad, select, "Open... or "Save...".  You can see the "Encoding" combobox at the bottom of this dialog.

[image]

Your dialog extension can basically hook most of the events while the file-open dialog box is open.  You can add additional control, get notified of when buttons are getting pressed, open/close notifications, and I think you can override the filename selected as well.